# sources.list broken in Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, debian, source.list

I have updated the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and ended up breaking it.  I've **restored it to its original contents** from my backup as follows

```
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

Now when I run `sudo apt-get update` I still get the same error message

```
E: Type '﻿deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Every other thread I've found related to this problem has said that it's a malformed line and it can be fixed by restoring the contents, but having looked at every single character with my eyelids peeled back, I can't see any differences from the original contents.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I ended up recovering the original OS, and the file's contents are visually the same.  My problem is now sorted, but I'm leaving this question up in case anyone finds a solution that doesn't involve completely overwriting their system.